# React js search doesn’t work on graphql pagination

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jsx, create-react-app, react-apollo

I created a search function using **react js** to filter a table of data fetched from graphql endpoint
**code :**

```
const SearchRes = () => {
    let filtredRes = data.Orders.edges
        .filter(item => item.node.shippingAddress.name === (query));

    let res = filtredRes.length === 0 ? data.Orders.edges : filtredRes;                                         
    return res;
}
```

**then t just do the following to get the data :**

```
SearchRes.map(...)
```

this works fine and i could do the search but when i implemented **graphql pagination** , the search stopped working on the results , it only works before clicking a button to get more results

**code :**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import Table  from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import moment from "moment";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import { DangerousChangeType } from 'graphql';
import Search from './Search'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

const GET_All_Orders = gql`
query Orders($input1: PaginationInput) {
    Orders(input: $input1){
     pageInfo {
       hasNextPage
       hasPreviousPage
     }
     edges{
       cursor
       node {
          id
          closed
          email
          createdAt
          updatedAt
          cancelledAt
          displayFinancialStatus
          displayFulfillmentStatus
          lineItems{
            edges{
              node {
                customAttributes{
                  key
                  value
                }
                id
                quantity
                title
                variant{
                  id
                  image {
                    altText
                    id
                    src
                  }
                  title
                  weight
                  weightUnit
                  price
                }
              }
            }
          }
          shippingAddress { 
            name
          }
         phone
         subtotalPrice
         totalPrice
         totalRefunded
         totalTax
         processedAt
       }
     }
   }
 }
`;


export default function AllOrders({ input1 }) {
    const { loading, error, data  , fetchMore} = useQuery(
        GET_All_Orders,
        {
            variables: {
                "input1": {
                    "num": 20,
                }
            },
        }
    );
    let date = new Date();
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    if (loading) return <h4>読み込み中...</h4>;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;
    
    const SearchRes = () => {
        let filtredRes = data.Orders.edges
            .filter(
                item => (
                    item.node.shippingAddress.name === (query) ||
                    item.node.email === (query)
                )
            );                                     
        let res = filtredRes.length === 0 ? data.Orders.edges : filtredRes;                                      
        return res;
    }

    return (
        <div>
           <Row > 
    <Col xs={10}> <h5>すべての注文</h5></Col>
    <Col><h5>  日付 : <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">
     
 { date}
            </Moment> </h5></Col>
  </Row>
   
 <br/>
 <Search getQuery={(q) => setQuery(q)} />
 <br/>
 <Table responsive hover size="sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    
    <th className="allOrders">注文日</th>
    <th className="allOrders">名前</th>
    <th className="allOrders">注文者メールアドレス</th>
    <th className="allOrders" >配送状態</th>
    <th className="allOrders" >支払状況</th>
      <th className="allOrders" >合計金額</th>
      <th className="allOrders" >詳細</th>
 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 {SearchRes().map(({ edges ,node :{id , createdAt , displayFulfillmentStatus , displayFinancialStatus , totalPrice , email , shippingAddress: { 
            name
          } }}) => (
    
    
    <tr key={id}>
      
  
      <td>    <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">
       {createdAt}
            </Moment></td>
            <td>{ name} </td>  
      <td>{ email} </td>

      {displayFulfillmentStatus == "FULFILLED" ? <td className="success">配送済み</td> :  <td className="failed">未配送</td>}
    
 
 
 
       
      {displayFinancialStatus == "PAID" ? <td>支払済み</td> : <td>未払い</td> }
      <td>{totalPrice} </td>
      <td>  
      <Link to={`/orders/${id}`} className="btn btn-light">
      詳細
          </Link></td>
   
    </tr>
    
    

  ))}
  </tbody>
</Table>
    
            {/* button responsible for the pagination */}
            <div className="text-center">
                <Button
                    variant="light"
                    onClick={() => {
                        fetchMore({
                            variables: {
                                "input1": {
                                    "num": 20,
                                    "cursor": data.Orders.edges[data.Orders.edges.length - 1].cursor
                                }
                            },
                            updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                                fetchMoreResult.Orders.edges = [
                                    ...prevResult.Orders.edges,
                                    ...fetchMoreResult.Orders.edges
                                ];
                                return fetchMoreResult;
                            }
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    もっと
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**maybe the issue is :**

1 ) i think the problem is because the button fetch a different table maybe that's why the function doesn't search it .

2. maybe because of the **num variable** because it is like the first parameter in graphql , you should specify how many result you should get so when i write  **"num": 20** in the button it will always return the first 20 result not the results after the cursor

Comment: `filtredRes.length === 0 ? data.Orders.edges :  filtredRes ` why this? No match so return all ? And it seems that `SearchRes` is not used in your code.

Comment: yes when i don't search for anything i want all the rows to be shows but when i search only the correct results will be fetched . i edited the code lease check it ( the ssearchfunction works at first but when i click the pagination button it doesn't work )

Comment: I think you should  use this `query ? filtredRes : data.Orders.edges`. When `query` is empty, show all results, when `query` is not empty, show the filtered result. If no record matched, Nothing should be showed.

Comment: can you modify the function like you said in a comment or response  ? thanks

Comment: Why does the button fetch a different table when it is the fetchMore function of the same query? Also, which Apollo version are you using? Apollo 2 or 3?

Comment: i'm usiing apollo 3 , the button fetch the same table not the next results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `SearchRes` function should be

```js
const SearchRes = () => {
    let filtredRes = data.Orders.edges
        .filter(item => item.node.shippingAddress.name === (query) ||
                    item.node.email === (query));

    let res = query ? filtredRes : data.Orders.edges;                                         
    return res;
}
```

When query is empty, which means the user let the search input empty, all result should be showed, and when the user enter something in the search input, only the filtered result should be showed, even if there is nothing matched.
I don't know whether its the real reason of your bug, but I think it's really a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are clearly missing an offset in your query. In your `fetchMore` query, you still pass `num: 20` as a variable, when in your own words

> maybe because of the num variable because it is like the first parameter in graphql , you should specify how many result you should get so when i write "num": 20 in the button it will always return the first 20 result not the results after the cursor

Yes, so you will always get the first 20 results, no matter how often you fetch. I don't know your backend implementation, but basically the `offset` is the parameter from which the results should start returning, so if you pass `offset: 10, num: 5`, you should get the items 11 - 15.

So in order for your query to work, it should look like this:

```
query Orders($input1: PaginationInput, offset: Int) {
```

Comment: i used the cursor to indicate the records from which the results should start returning , **"cursor": data.Orders.edges[data.Orders.edges.length - 1].cursor** . my intention is to pass the first 20 results after the element that contains that cursor .